# Does pyspark have an equivalent of org.apache.spark.functions.transform?

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

[org.apache.spark.functions.transform](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/java/org/apache/spark/sql/functions.html#transform-org.apache.spark.sql.Column-scala.Function1-) applies a function to each element of an array (new in spark 3.0)
However, the pyspark [docs](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/pyspark.sql.html) don't mention an equivalent function

(there's pyspark.sql.DataFrame.transform - but it's for transforming DataFrames, not array elements)

Answer (score 1):

EDIT:

To avoid UDFs, you can use F.expr('transform ...'):

```
import pyspark.sql.functions as F
from pyspark.sql.types import IntegerType

df = spark.createDataFrame([[[1,2]],[[3,4]]]).toDF('col')
df.show()
+------+
|   col|
+------+
|[1, 2]|
|[3, 4]|
+------+

df.select(F.expr('transform(col, x -> x+1)').alias('transform')).show()
+---------+
|transform|
+---------+
|   [2, 3]|
|   [4, 5]|
+---------+
```

Old answer:

IIUC, I think the equivalent is UDF. `x+1` is the function to be applied.

```
import pyspark.sql.functions as F
from pyspark.sql.types import IntegerType

add = F.udf(lambda arr: [x+1 for x in arr], ArrayType(IntegerType()))
df.select(add('col')).show()
+-------------+
|<lambda>(col)|
+-------------+
|       [2, 3]|
|       [4, 5]|
+-------------+
```

Comment: the intention of transform is to avoid the usage of UDF functions for this functionality